# Feynman loop diagram with off-shell momenta

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, feynman-diagrams, effective-field-theory

I wanted to evaluate the Wilson Coefficients for the process $c\rightarrow su\bar{d}$ since wherever I look they seem to be always given, for the exception of Schwart's book Quantum Field theory and the Standard Model where the calculation is done in a slightly different manner to what I'm used to.

For reference, I'm following [G. Buchalla et al. review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9512380). In equation III.42 they give the result of the calculation for the one loop corrections to the cited amplitude. I want to reproduce this result and the results of III.45-III.46 which are the amplitudes for the effective theory.

To evaluate the relevant Feynman diagrams (in fig. 2 and 3 of the review) they use the Feynman gauge and *take all the external quark lines massless and carrying the off-shell momentum* $p$. What I understand then is that all external lines carry momentum $p$ which in turn means that the $W$ propagator should carry zero momentum. So, if this is what they are intending, for diagram in figure $2$ (a) (which I put here for reference)

$\hspace{100pt}$[image: Feynman amplitude]

I should get the following amplitude

$$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\bar{u}_u^i(p)\left(-ig_sT^a_{ij}\gamma_\mu\right)\frac{-i}{\not p-\not k}\left(-ig\gamma_\alpha P_L\right)\frac{-i}{\not p-\not k}\left(-ig_sT^b_{jl}\gamma_\nu\right)u^l_d(p)\frac{-ig^{\mu\nu}\delta^{ab}}{k^2+i\epsilon}\frac{-ig^{\alpha\beta}}{-M_W^2+i\epsilon}\bar{u}_s(p)(-ig\gamma_\beta P_L)u_c(p)$$

I made the indices evident where needed, $P_L = \dfrac{1-\gamma_5}{2}$ is the left spinor projector and $T^a$ are $SU(3)$ generators.

> Now the question: Is this amplitude correct? Is the fact that the $W$ carries zero momentum a sensible choice? I understand that is a choice that we can make since the $W$ is virtual and so off-shell, but it's not clear to me if this is what the authors imply in their text. Because it seems to me that this amplitude is nowhere different from the amplitude I would get in the effective theory.

Answer (score 0):

They probably want to do this in the low energy limit which means taking $p_{1},p_{2},k_{1},k_{2} \approx p \ll M_{w}$ where $p$ signals incoming momentum and $k$ outgoing so that they can get the low energy Wilson coefficient.

Comment: And this makes sense, but in this limit what momentum should I use for the $W$ propagator?